# How to fetch all nodes in neo4j for relationship (Node A)-[Relation A]->(Node B)-[Relation B]->(Node C)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Graph has two types of nodes:

- Rule (has name attribute)
- Variable (has name attributes)

Has following relationships:

- Rule-[:depends_on]-> Variable
- Rule-[:targets]-> Variable

#### Cypher Query to create sample graph

```
CREATE
  (rule1:Rule {name:'rule_1'}),
  (rule2:Rule {name:'rule_2'}),
  (rule3:Rule {name:'rule_3'}),
  (rule4:Rule {name:'rule_4'}),
  (variable1:Variable {name:'variable_1'}),
  (variable2:Variable {name:'variable_2'}),
  (variable3:Variable {name:'variable_3'}),
  (variable4:Variable {name:'variable_4'}),
  (variable5:Variable {name:'variable_5'}),
  (variable6:Variable {name:'variable_6'}),
  (variable7:Variable {name:'variable_7'}),
  (rule1)-[:targets]->(variable2),
  (rule1)-[:targets]->(variable3),
  (rule2)-[:targets]->(variable4),
  (rule2)-[:targets]->(variable5),
  (rule3)-[:targets]->(variable6),
  (rule3)-[:targets]->(variable7),
  (rule4)-[:targets]->(variable3),
  (rule1)-[:depends_on]->(variable1),
  (rule2)-[:depends_on]->(variable2),
  (rule3)-[:depends_on]->(variable3),
  (rule4)-[:depends_on]->(variable4)
```

#### Query Requirement

Given a rule name recursively fetch all possible rule chains that can be triggered by it using a cypher query. That is, if Rule 1 is triggered then it would trigger Rule 2 (variable 2 is targeted by rule 1 and is dependency for rule 2) & Rule 3 (variable 3 is targeted by rule 1 and is dependency for rule 3) and Rule 2 would trigger Rule 4 (variable 4 is targeted by rule 2 and is dependency for rule 4), which again can trigger Rule 3 (variable 3 is targeted by rule 4 and is dependency for rule 3).

##### Possible rule chain

```
Rule 1 -> Rule 2 -> Rule 4 -> Rule 3
Rule 1 -> Rule 3
```

Comment: I don't see any relation between rule1 and rule2 in your graph? What is the role of the variables, are they relevant for the question? How do you get from rule1 to rule2? Or from rule1 to rule3?

Comment: @knittl `(rule1)-[:targets]->(variable2)` & `(rule2)-[:depends_on]->(variable2)` these two relationships make Rule 1 -> Rule 2 chain

Comment: @knittl I have edited questions to add more details on how rule chain is formed using rule and variable. Hope this helps. Let me know if there are still ambiguous details, will add those based on queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple case with no cycles**

If you are using Neo4j 5.9+, you can use the following [quantified path pattern](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#quantified-path-patterns) to get each distinct rule chain:

```sql
MATCH path = (:Rule {name: 'rule_1'}) 
        (()-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule))+ (r) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (r)-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule) }
RETURN [n IN nodes(path) WHERE n:Rule | n.name] AS ruleChain
```

The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is there to ensure the results include only the complete rule chains and not any subsets of them, as it makes sure there are no more rules to expand the rule chain to.

**Handling cycles in the rules graph**

If there are cycles in the rules graph, the above will return all unique pathways. In such a case, separating out the cycle-free rule chains from the cycles attached to those rules would be useful. This query returns the cycle-free rule chains:

```sql
MATCH (a:Rule {name: 'rule_1'})
MATCH path = (a) (()-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule))+ (b) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (b)-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule) } 
AND COUNT { WITH path UNWIND nodes(path) AS n RETURN DISTINCT n } =
    size(nodes(path))
RETURN [n IN nodes(path) WHERE n:Rule | n.name] AS ruleChain
```

This returns all cycles that those rule chains encounter, including the variables they target:

```sql
MATCH (a:Rule {name: 'rule_1'})
MATCH path = (a) (()-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule))+
UNWIND [n IN nodes(path) WHERE n:Rule] AS node
WITH DISTINCT node
MATCH path = (node) (()-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule))+ (node)
WHERE COUNT { WITH path UNWIND nodes(path)[..-1] AS n RETURN DISTINCT n } =
      size(nodes(path)[..-1])
RETURN [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] AS cycle
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I am looking for output which only contains rule names in form of list of lists or something similar like this `[['rule_1', 'rule_2', 'rule_4', 'rule_3'], ['rule_1', 'rule_3']`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it's doable. I've changed the results to be a list comprehension, showing just the rule names in each path.

Comment: Great. I have just tried executing both new queries. First one with just rules is working, but second one which includes variables along with rules is returning empty result.

Comment: Yes, on your sample data where there are no cycles, you should get no results with the second query.

Comment: Ok. But I was thinking single query should work irrespective of the fact that graph contains cycles or not. First query is good enough for my use case, I can build on it ( & @cybersam's query) for further use cases.

Comment: It works in that there are no cycles on the rule chain emanating from rule_1 i.e. we expect no results. In the section "Handling cyles in the rules graph" I suggested a way to capture any cycles was to separate the cycle-free paths from the cycles themselves, as the alternative would be a proliferation of possible ways of traversing. But it's only something to revisit if and when you hit this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This answer attempts to improve @FinbarGood's answer.

In the real world (and I presume in your use case as well), it is very common for a rule to both set *and* depend on the same variable (e.g., the rule may increment a numeric variable).

So, let's add some more rules to your sample graph:

```
MATCH (r1:Rule {name:'rule_1'}), (v3:Variable {name:'variable_3'}), (v7:Variable {name:'variable_7'})
CREATE
  (r5:Rule {name:'rule_5'}),
  (r6:Rule {name:'rule_6'}),
  (v8:Variable {name:'variable_8'}),
  (v9:Variable {name:'variable_9'}),
  (v10:Variable {name:'variable_10'})
CREATE (r1)-[:targets]->(v8)<-[:depends_on]-(r1)
CREATE (r1)-[:targets]->(v9)<-[:depends_on]-(r5)-[:targets]->(v10)<-[:depends_on]-(r1)
CREATE (r6)-[:depends_on]->(v7)
CREATE (r1)-[:depends_on]->(v3)
```

The resulting graph will look like this:

[image]

In the resulting chains, we should include "looping" chains that start and end at the same `Rule`, since those are valid rule paths. But once we have returned to the starting `Rule`, I will assume that we want to stop expanding any further (if there are multiple possible paths from that `Rule`), to avoid redundancy.

Here is a query that returns the names of the rules and variables along each chain (variable names are included because there can be multiple ways to connect the same sequence of rules):

```
MATCH path = (r0:Rule {name: 'rule_1'}) (()-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule))+ (r)
WHERE (r = r0 AND NOT r0 IN NODES(path)[1..-1]) OR
  NOT (r0 IN NODES(path)[1..] OR EXISTS((r)-[:targets]->(:Variable)<-[:depends_on]-(:Rule)))
RETURN [n IN NODES(path)|n.name] AS chain
```

The results are as expected:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│chain                                                                 │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│["rule_1", "variable_8", "rule_1"]                                    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│["rule_1", "variable_3", "rule_1"]                                    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│["rule_1", "variable_9", "rule_5", "variable_10", "rule_1"]           │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│["rule_1", "variable_3", "rule_3", "variable_7", "rule_6"]            │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│["rule_1", "variable_2", "rule_2", "variable_4", "rule_4", "variable_3│
│", "rule_1"]                                                          │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│["rule_1", "variable_2", "rule_2", "variable_4", "rule_4", "variable_3│
│", "rule_3", "variable_7", "rule_6"]                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

NOTE: To avoid endless looping in the rule chain, rules like `rule_1` may need to be forced to only run once. This is actually rather easy to do using `MATCH` clauses, since a `MATCH` clause will only return results in which a relationship appears at most once.

Comment: Deferring to the OP for the final word, but it does seem the circular dependencies you are trying to accommodate for here should be _ruled out_ by the model.

Comment: Suppose rule_1 was "increment each input variable". Filtering out loops would omit chains involving "variable_8" and "variable_3", which would seem to be omitting useful information. But perhaps the OP needs to change the query and output format to make the rule behavior clearer, as it is currently hard to understand what is happening in loop chains.

Comment: By design, you can definitely have loops between rules, that is, something like Rule 1 -> Rule 2 -> Rule 1 can exist. But for the sake of this query, it is something that I wasn't look to solve right away. I just wanted to understand how to write queries of such behaviors. Having said that, this is appreciated and helps me to move forward quickly for solving the problem statement that I have.